# Angular datatables dtOptions are updated only from the second click

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

I'm trying to update(rerender) angular datatable with new dtOptions

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success m-r-sm" id="filter" (click)="filter()">
   {{'apply' | translate}}
</button>
```

```js
filter() {
const that = this;
  this.dtOptions = {
    pagingType: 'full_numbers',
    pageLength: 20,
    serverSide: true,
    processing: true,
    searching: false,
    ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {
      that.service.getExtendedCdrByCriteria(this.selectedDirection, this.selectedDisposition, this.caller, this.calledNumber, this.from, this.to, dataTablesParameters).subscribe(resp => {
        that.extendedCdrs = resp.data;
        console.log('ajax call');

        callback({
          recordsTotal: resp.recordsTotal,
          recordsFiltered: resp.recordsFiltered,
          data: []
        });
      });
    },
    columns: [
      { data: 'direction' },
      { data: 'datetime' },
      { data: 'callerNumber' },
      { data: 'calledNumber' },
      { data: 'timeOnHold' },
      { data: 'callTotalTime' },
      { data: 'trunkName' },
      { data: 'disposition' },
      { data: 'recordingfile' }
    ],
  };
  this.rerender();
}

rerender(): void {
  try {
    this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
      dtInstance.destroy();
      this.dtTrigger.next();
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

When I click on button first time, ajax calls had not executed, and table rerender with the same data, but when had clicked second time on the button, this.dtOptions updates and rerender table with correct updated data. how to make it run the first button click?

Answer (score 0):

I think your `rerender()` method is executed faster than ajax was completed. Try to remove your `rerender()` method at all.